# Problems launching .ps1 script with further "dot sourced" scripts via shortcut / paths not found

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I have a ps1 script, which is launched via shortcut.
Shortcut properties:

```
Target: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Temp\myfile.ps1"
Start in: "C:\Temp"
Run as admin set true
```

Content of myfile.ps1:

```
. .\ps\file1.ps1
. .\ps\file2.ps1

Clear-Host 
function1
function2
```

function1 is included in file1.ps1, function2 in file2.ps1

error-message:

```
function1: The term 'function1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At C:\Temp\myfile.ps1:1 char:1
+ function1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (function1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Same for `function2` in `file2.ps1`

If launched it via Powershell console, it works as intended.
Probably sth is wrong / missing regarding the launch-in directory or similar?

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem, but I suggest changing your approach (as you've since confirmed, this fixes your problem):

I'm assuming you want to **[dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) your helper `.ps1` files from a location *relative to the location of the executing script*** rather than relative to the *current* (working) directory.

- The [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) contains the full path of the directory in which the executing scripts is located.

Therefore, modify your script as follows:

```bash
# Dot-source the helper scripts from a subdirectory 
# of the directory in which the running script is located.
. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ps\file1.ps1)
. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ps\file2.ps1)

Clear-Host 
function1
function2
```